# The basic OpenGL sample always freezes in Android 1.5 when changing orientation

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have begun learning OpenGL ES under Android 1.5 (I use the emulator and an HTC Magic device). However, even for the simplest of their samples, the one that only renders a blank screen, if you switch the orientation several times (switching like ~5 times between portrait and landscape is usually enough), the app freezes and I need to force close it.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Can anyone else reproduce it? You should be able to, it's the same in the emulator too.

Thanks in advance,
Cosmin

Update: The LogCat output differs when running with the debugger attached.

```
DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(61): pid 3598 requesting gpu core (owner = -1)
```

versus

```
WARN/SurfaceFlinger(61): timeout expired mFreezeDisplay=1, mFreezeCount=1
WARN/WindowManager(61): App freeze timeout expired.
WARN/WindowManager(61): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{43c7adb0 token=HistoryRecord{43c7a900 {ro.brite.android.nehe01/ro.brite.android.nehe01.GlApp}}}
WARN/SurfaceComposerClient(3598): lock_layer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) layer=1, lcblk=0x424340a0, state=00000042 (was 00000042)
```

Comment: Do you get any debug information like Java error messages?

Comment: No, I've run it again in the debugger, and no error messages were printed. On the other hand, it didn't freeze anymore this time, but it keeps getting heavier on the CPU each time I make a switch. I'll try on the HTC Magic now as well...

Comment: This is really weird. With the debugger attached, it doesn't freeze. But as soon as I unplug the USB connector, after a few switches, it freezes. Also, I can see that the switch isn't complete anymore, with the old title bar being still present in the old location, but with very low visibility, almost black. The app doesn't respond anymore to the Back button (or other input). After a while, I force close it. It seems like some resources are being left active, because it becomes less responsive over time.

Comment: late to the party but can you post your code ?